# How can I animate a flex container with a conditional react-component inside?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, antd

I have a table with a custom right side control, where the user can set the columns visibility as well as reorder them. Upon clicking a button, the control expands and the user can now make changes. The basic functionality is there. I am now trying to make the transition a smoother and that is where I am failing.

Here is the minimal markup that is rendered:

```
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  }}
>
  <div style={{ flex: "auto" }}>
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} pagination={"false"} />
  </div>
  <div
    style={{
      flex: hasExpandedControls ? "2 1 1" : "0 0 1",
      transition: "all 500ms ease-in-out"
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        {hasExpandedControls ? (
          <Tree
            checkable
            draggable
            treeData={columnsTree}
            checkedKeys={visibleColumns.map((col) => col.key)}
            onCheck={handleCheck}
            onDrop={handleDrop}
            style={{ marginRight: "0.5em" }}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
      <div>
        <div style={{ padding: "50% 0", height: 0, width: "40px" }}>
          <Button
            onClick={() => setHasExpandedControls((prev) => !prev)}
            style={{
              marginLeft: ".5em",
              display: "block",
              transformOrigin: "top left",
              // transform: 'rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%)',
              transform: "rotate(90deg) translate(0, -100%)",
              marginTop: "-50%"
            }}
          >
            Spalten
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Clicking the button triggers a state change, which causes the `Tree` to be rendered and in this instance the `div` 'snaps' to its full width. I am failing to accomplish my goal using css transitions, so I was wondering if there was an easier way to accomplish my goal.
I've tried setting the transition on various wrapping elements and *all* elements, but the 'snap' into existence remains.

Codepen to reproduce: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-17-3-forked-yq2u7?file=/index.jshttps://codesandbox.io/s/gu4hs

Comment: If you don't mind having the conditional component present in the DOM when it's hidden, you can just set the `width` or `maxWidth` to zero instead. Then when it's visible you increase the value, which lets the component slide in if you set a `transition` property

Comment: At this point I don't mind, as the footprint of it is relative inexpensive. I'll give it a go